# getting error when calling dotnet grpc service from golang client

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go, grpc-dotnet

Csharp:

```cs
// configure application:
app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                // Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client.
                // To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<SSOAdapterGRPCImplementation>();
            });

// configure services:
services.AddGrpc();
```

Go code:

```golang
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    addr := "localhost:5001"
    log.Print("trying to connect to grpc")
    var opts []grpc.DialOption
    opts = append(opts, grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions())
    certFilePath := `c:\Keys\local-v2\localhost.cer`
    cred, err := credentials.NewClientTLSFromFile(certFilePath, "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    opts = append(opts, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(cred))

    conn, err := grpc.Dial(addr, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    c := ssoadapter.NewSSOAdapterGRPCClient(conn)
    resp, err :=c.GetConfiguration(ctx, &ssoadapter.GetConfigurationRequest{
        AdapterId:            1,
    })
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("GetConfiguration [%v]",resp)

    resp2, err := c.SetConfiguration(ctx, &ssoadapter.SetConfigurationRequest{
        PartnerId: 100,
        AdapterId: 1,
        Configuration: map[string]string{
            "k1": "v1",
            "k2": "v2",
        },
        Signature: "123",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("SetConfiguration: %v", resp2)

}
```

when calling this I get and error from the client code :

```
2020/07/28 10:05:29 trying to connect to grpc
2020/07/28 10:05:29 rpc error: code = Internal desc = server closed the stream without sending trailers

Process finished with exit code 1
```

on server side  get:

```
INFO 2020-07-28 10:04:03,867 class:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics topic:null server:IL-ARTHURVA-VIM ip:::1 reqid:0HM1IOCJG13HA:00000005 partner:null action:null uid:null msg:Request finished in 7.4006ms 404
INFO 2020-07-28 10:05:29,273 class:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics topic:null server:IL-ARTHURVA-VIM ip:null reqid:null partner:null action:null uid:null msg:Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:5001/SSOAdapterGRPC/GetConfiguration application/grpc
DEBUG 2020-07-28 10:05:29,277 class:Core.Middleware.RequestLoggingMiddleware topic:null server:IL-ARTHURVA-VIM ip:::1 reqid:0HM1IOCJG13HB:00000001 partner:null action:null uid:null msg:Url: https://localhost:5001/SSOAdapterGRPC/GetConfiguration
Headers: Content-Type:application/grpc,Host:localhost:5001,TE:trailers,User-Agent:grpc-go/1.30.0,:method:POST,:scheme:https,:path:/SSOAdapterGRPC/GetConfiguration,:authority:localhost:5001
Body:

INFO 2020-07-28 10:05:29,278 class:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware topic:null server:IL-ARTHURVA-VIM ip:::1 reqid:0HM1IOCJG13HB:00000001 partner:null action:null uid:null msg:Executing endpoint 'gRPC - /SSOAdapterGRPC/GetConfiguration'
ERROR 2020-07-28 10:05:29,280 class:Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler topic:null server:IL-ARTHURVA-VIM ip:::1 reqid:0HM1IOCJG13HB:00000001 partner:null action:null uid:null msg:Error reading message.
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Incomplete message.")
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions.ReadSingleMessageAsync[T](PipeReader input, HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext, Func`2 deserializer)
INFO 2020-07-28 10:05:29,282 class:Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler topic:null server:IL-ARTHURVA-VIM ip:::1 reqid:0HM1IOCJG13HB:00000001 partner:null action:null uid:null msg:Error status code 'Internal' raised.
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="Incomplete message.")
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions.ReadSingleMessageAsync[T](PipeReader input, HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext, Func`2 deserializer)
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.CallHandlers.UnaryServerCallHandler`3.HandleCallAsyncCore(HttpContext httpContext, HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext)
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.CallHandlers.ServerCallHandlerBase`3.<HandleCallAsync>g__AwaitHandleCall|8_0(HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext, Method`2 method, Task handleCall)
INFO 2020-07-28 10:05:29,286 class:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware topic:null server:IL-ARTHURVA-VIM ip:::1 reqid:0HM1IOCJG13HB:00000001 partner:null action:null uid:null msg:Executed endpoint 'gRPC - /SSOAdapterGRPC/GetConfiguration'
INFO 2020-07-28 10:05:29,288 class:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics topic:null server:IL-ARTHURVA-VIM ip:::1 reqid:0HM1IOCJG13HB:00000001 partner:null action:null uid:null msg:Request finished in 14.4426ms 200 application/grpc
```

Comment: It may be useful to try a different client w/ the .NET server ([`grpcurl`](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) is excellent) and|or a different server w/ the Golang client to eliminate which of the two (or both) is the problem. I assume `ssoadaptor` is your `protoc`-generated implementation.